# Orange, Python: list index out of range Association Rules - how does the data need to look like?

Tags: python, orange

I'm playing around with the Orange Association Rules sample.
[Orange Doc](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html)
My code looks pretty much like in the docs:

```
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("order_data.basket")

rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(data, support = 0.5)

print "%5s   %5s" % ("supp", "conf")
for r in rules:
    print "%5.3f   %5.3f   %s" % (r.support, r.confidence, r)

inducer = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(support = 0.5, store_examples = True)
itemsets = inducer.get_itemsets(data)
# print itemsets
print [data.domain[i].name for i in itemsets[5][0]]
```

And it's working with the data from Orange

> our, two, weapons, are, fear, and, surprise, and, ruthless, efficiency
>   our, three, weapons, are, fear, surprise, and, ruthless, efficiency, and, an, almost, fanatical, devotion, to, the, Pope
>   our
>   amongst, our, weapons

But with my data I receive an error:

```
supp    conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inqui.py", line 15, in <module>
    print [data.domain[i].name for i in itemsets[5][0]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

That's my data:

```
Item1
Item2, Item2, Item2, Item2, Item7, Item7, Item7, Item7, Item7
Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item2
Item4, Item4
Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item1, Item2
Item5
```

I checked for spaces and used a barebone/short version of my data with 10 lines like in the example but I still receive this error.
Where does it come from?

Comment: The data seems to be correct - but I'm playing around with the support value and changing the number 5 to 2 or 3 or 4 in `itemsets[5][0]]` and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - so the result of itemsets seems to be different with the parameters (of course) but the question would be: What can it stomach?